# Using from another table for radioList's select options

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to use **another** table data for select options of radioList.

for getting better I mean, I want something like bellow code:

```
            $form->field($model_add, 'link_type')->radioList([

               'another table ID 1' => 'another table title 1',
               'another table ID 2' => 'another table title 2',
            ]);
```

Can I use foreach inside it, for options?

If my question is not clear, ask me what you want to know more.

Comment: Could you update your question with example of such data?

Comment: @Bizley Is it clear now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ArrayHelper](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-array.html#building-maps) for this. Assuming `$array` looks like this:

```
[
    ['id' => 1, 'title' => 'aaa'],
    ['id' => 2, 'title' => 'bbb'],
    // ...
]
```

You can map it to

```
[
    1 => 'aaa',
    2 => 'bbb',
    // ...
]
```

like this:

```
$form->field($model_add, 'link_type')->radioList(
    \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($array, 'id', 'title')
);
```

Comment: Yes it works, I have used it before in DropDownList, but I've forgotten it. anyway, I appreciate you. please vote this question.

Answer (score 1):

It also same like Bizley answer,little clear

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'fieldName')->radioList( 
        ArrayHelper::map(TableName::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
        ['prompt' => 'Please Select']);?>
```